# Adding a dijit to another dijit's containerNode in dojo

Tags: javascript, dom, dojo

I have a custom built dijit (`Timeline`) with a `containerNode` that contains other custom built dijits (`Tracks`). How can I programmatically add a new `Track` to the `containerNode` such that the `Track` will not actually get created/rendered until it is in the proper place in the DOM?

If I create the new `Track` and then place it in the DOM via `domConstruct.place`, for example, the rendering is incorrect because the track's rendering depends on itself already being in the DOM.

Comment: Looks like I just needed to call `.startup()`---whoops!

Answer (score 1):

Timeline should use the dijit._Container mixin and then you can add the children widgets using 
the addChild method.

```
dojo.declare("Timeline", [dijit._Widget, dijit._Container], {
    ...
});

timeline.addChild(child);
```